# Learning how to build an array list that regenerates

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, addeventlistener

Looking to build a multiple choice test that when a button is clicked for answering question, the next questions and answers load - been looking at local storage and ran a debug with console that gave me the following error msg " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" first time coder so any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you

```
// Questions + Answers from local storage//
    
    var testquestions = document.getElementById("question");
    var testanswers = document.getElementById("answer");
    var comment = document.getElementById("msg");
    var saveButton = document.getElementById("save");
    var savedAnswer = document.getElementById("savedAnswer");
    
    function saveLastAnswer() {
        var testResult = {
        testquestions: questions.value,
        testanswers: answers.value,
        comment: comment.value.trim()
    };
    // setItem to store oject in storage and JSON.stringfy to convert it as a string.//
    localStorage.setItem("testResult",JSON.stringify(testResult));
    }
    
    function renderLastAnswer () {
        //Use JSON.parse to covert text to Javascript object
        var lastAnswer = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("testResult"));
        //Check if data returned is correct or in correct//
        if (lastAnswer !== null){
            document.getElementById("savedAnswer"). innerHTML = lastAnswer.answer;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    
    saveButton.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    saveLastAnswer();
    renderLastAnswer();
    });
    
    //Init function //
    function init () {
      renderLastAnswer();
    }
    init ();
```

---

HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"></html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css"/>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="countdwnclock">Seconds left:<span id ="time-left"> 60</span></div>
        <div class="container"></div>
        <!--Questions 1-->
        var = question1
        <div class="copy">"Commonly used data types DO NOT include:"</div>
        <ul class="answers" id="question1">

            <input type = "radio" name="q1" value = "a" id="q1a">1.strings</label>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type = "radio" name="q1" value = "b" id="q1b">2.booleans</label>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type = "radio" name="q1" value = "c" id="q1c">2.booleans</label>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type = "radio" name="q1" value = "d" id="q1d">3.alerts</label>
        </ul>

        <!--Quesions 2-->
        <div class="container"></div>
        <div class="copy">The condition in an if/else statement is enclosed within____.</div>
        <ul class="answers" id="question2">

            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a">1.quotes</label>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b">2.curly brackets</label>  
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2c">3.parenthesis</label>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2d">4.square brackets</label>
    </ul>
    <!--Question 3-->
    <div class="container"></div>
        <div class="copy">Arrays in Javascript can be used to store____.</div>
        <ul class="answers" id="question3">

            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" id="q3a">1.numbers & strings</label>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" id="q3b">2.other arrays</label>  
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" id="q3c">3.booleans</label>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" id="q3d">4.all the above</label>
    </ul>
    <!--Question 4-->
    <div class="container"></div>
        <div class="copy">String values must be enclosed within______when being assigned to variables.</div>
        <ul class="answers" id="question4">

            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="a" id="q4a">1.commas</label>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="b" id="q4b">2.curly brackets</label>  
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="a" id="q4c">3.quotes</label>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="c" id="q4d">4.parenthesis</label>
    </ul>
    <!--Question 5-->
    <div class="container"></div>
        <div class="copy">A very useful tool used during development and debugging for printing content to the debugger is____.</div>
        <ul class="answers" id="question4">

            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="a" id="q5a">1.Javascript</label>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="b" id="q5b">2.terminal/bash</label>  
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="a" id="q5c">3.for loops</label>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="c" id="q5d">4.console log</label>
    </ul>

    </body>
       
        </html>
```

---

```
  /**** CSS STYLES ***/ 

.text{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: x-large;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

.copy {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.center {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.container { 
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border: none; 
  }

/****Questions****/
.questions{ 
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: purple;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;

  }
  /***Buttons***/
  .button:hover {background-color: purple;
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  .button:active {
      box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
      transform: translateY(4px);
  }

  .start{ 
    padding: 15px 25px;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: purple;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  }
  .button:hover {background-color: purple;}
  .button:active {
      box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
      transform: translateY(4px);
  }

  /***Unordered lists***/
ul{
      list-style-type: none;
      margin-left: 40%;
      padding: 5px 5px;
      font-size: 24px;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      text-decoration: none;
      outline: none;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: purple;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 15px;
      box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: medium;
      width: 200px;
    }

    input{
      visibility: hidden;
    }

.wrapper{
  height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border: none; 
}

.countdwnclock{
 position: absolute;
 left: 1000px;
 border: none;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: medium;

}
```

Comment: Plz, share the HTML/CSS.

Comment: sorry, Manas where would I be able to upload that?

Comment: Edit the above question.

Comment: Why does you HTML has `</label>`?

Comment: There is no element with the id `save` in the whole `HTML` and that is obvious it will return an error because you are calling the `addEventListener` on something that does not exist.

Comment: The HTML is it self full of errors...

Comment: Why are `input` inside the `ul`?

Comment: Why are these empty tags `<div class="container"></div>` there?

Comment: First, correct the basic HTML errors that go to Javascript

Comment: Making this code error-free it just the same as rewriting it.

Comment: Cheers Manas looks like I have a lot more work to do :)